# iOS Simulator is black on app execution

Tags: ios, xcode5, nsunknownkeyexception

I am running xcode 5.1.1 and have been trying to learn objective C / iOS development.  Right now whenever I try to run my code on the emulator (I do not have an actual device atm) it comes up with a black screen.  Code can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/calculatorproblems/files/Calculator.zip/download).   Compiling and running gives me the following error:

```
2014-08-23 10:42:57.429 Calculator[1862:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception         'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<XYZViewController 0xe436640> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key didgetPressed.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ed1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156c8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0187cfe1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x0122cd9e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x011991d7 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
5   Foundation                          0x01198731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
6   Foundation                          0x011fab0a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x004e31f4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157e7de -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
9   CoreFoundation                      0x017e876a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
10  UIKit                               0x004e1d4d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
11  UIKit                               0x0034a6f5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
12  UIKit                               0x0034ae9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
13  UIKit                               0x0034b0d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
14  UIKit                               0x0034b5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
15  UIKit                               0x0026b267 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
16  UIKit                               0x0026b5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
17  UIKit                               0x0026b86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
18  UIKit                               0x002763c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
19  UIKit                               0x00226bc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
20  UIKit                               0x0022b667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
21  UIKit                               0x0023ff92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
22  UIKit                               0x00240555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
23  UIKit                               0x0022d250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
24  GraphicsServices                    0x037e2f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
25  GraphicsServices                    0x037e2a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
26  CoreFoundation                      0x01768ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
27  CoreFoundation                      0x017689db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0179368c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
29  CoreFoundation                      0x017929d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
30  CoreFoundation                      0x017927eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
31  UIKit                               0x0022ad9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
32  UIKit                               0x0022cf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
33  Calculator                          0x00002c8d main + 141
34  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e34701 start + 1
35  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have attempted the following things, and so far nothing has worked

1) checked the deployment info, it has the main interface set to main

2) double checked all break points to turn them off and disabled all of them through Debug->Disable Breakpoints

3) Reset Content and Settings on the iOS Simulator.

4) Checked the issue with the LLDB Debugger, however from what I have read the issue is no longer present with the 5.1.1 xcode.

5) checked the local host is still set to 127.0.0.1

Thanks!
- Terryn

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked out your project. The IBActions for the digits (`didgetPressed:`) are connected correctly, but the IBOutlets are not connected correctly (the property `didgetPressed` does not exist).

It will work when you delete the referencing outlets in the storyboard (see picture).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error message tells us what's wrong:

> 2014-08-23 10:42:57.429 Calculator[1862:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception         'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key didgetPressed.'

From this we can deduce that, in your storyboard (or xib), you have an object of class `XYZViewController`.  That object once had an outlet named `didgetPressed`, and you connected that outlet to something else in the storyboard.

Later, you changed something about your project that removed the `didgetPressed` outlet from that object, but you didn't disconnect the outlet in your storyboard.  For example, maybe you changed the outlet name in your Objective-C code to `didGetPressed`, or maybe you deleted the outlet and changed it to an action, or maybe you changed the object's class (and the prior class had the `didgetPressed` outlet).

You need to find the `XYZViewController` object in your storyboard and disconnect the `didgetPressed` outlet.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory you can remove that by opening storyboard select XYZViewController goto connection inspector under Utilities panel and remove binding of didgetPressed.

I have check you code just select button with 7 as title and remove it's referencing outlet and run again it will work.